# I got this error code in my vps when i run the docker

Tags: docker, bots, telegram, vps

In my vps i try to run telegram bot with docker. when i give this command (sudo docker run scroogex/bot1) it will going start and popup this error .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Film-Detective/Film-Detective.py", line 13, in <module>
    from database.ia_filterdb import Media
  File "/Film-Detective/database/ia_filterdb.py", line 11, in <module>
    from info import DATABASE_URI, DATABASE_NAME, COLLECTION_NAME, USE_CAPTION_FILTER
  File "/Film-Detective/info.py", line 16, in <module>
    API_ID = int(environ.get('API_ID', ''))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

already logging docker and daemon is started.

how can i fix it? i already edited my info.py. also telegram api id

Comment: From the error it looks like you need to set the `API_ID` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message relates to `int(environ.get('API_ID', ''))`. If `API_ID` is not available in the environment then `environ.get()` reverts to the default you provided (`''`) but then this is passed as an argument to `int()` it generates an error because there is no clear way to get an integer from the empty string.

Try this:

```
sudo docker run -e API_ID=99 scroogex/bot1
```

That will set the `API_ID` environment variable. Choose an appropriate value for `API_ID`.

If you are defining your environment variables via a `.env` file then use:

```
sudo docker run --env-file .env scroogex/bot1
```